# Is there any chain complex $A_\bullet$ such that $H_n(A_\bullet)$ is $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ for all $n\in\mathbb{Z}$?

Tags: homological-algebra

Is there any chain complex $A_\bullet$ such that $H_n(A_\bullet)$ is $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ for all $n\in\mathbb{Z}$ and $H_n(A_\bullet/2A_\bullet)=\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$?

Answer (score 4):

What about $A_n=\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$ and $d_n=0$?

Comment: (More generally, the homology of any complex with zero differential is itself.)